# sheet.getDataValidations() returns an empty list when a cell is validated by a sequence on another sheet

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a workbook with two sheets:

1. Sheet1
2. Sheet2

And there is a sequence on Sheet2 at the range of A1 to A5:

- aa
- bb
- cc
- dd
- ee

And in Sheet1, the cell A1 is validated by the sequence in Sheet2.

[Excel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxc9S.png)

However, `sheet.getDataValidations()` returns an empty list for this case.
Did I miss something?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String filePath = "/Users/fujiexiang/ExcelWorkbook.xlsx";

        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(filePath));
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        System.out.println("" + dataValidations + " " + dataValidations.size());
    }
```

"[] 0" was printed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Apache POI` bases on `Office Open XML` published for `Excel 2007`. And `Excel 2007` had not supported data validation list constraint coming directly from another worksheet. There had must be created a named range for the data validation list constraint. Now current `Excel` versions support data validation list constraint coming directly from another worksheet but of course not backwards compatible. That's why `apache poi` also cannot read those constraints as it only reads `CTDataValidations` which are from `Office Open XML` published for `Excel 2007`.

In the `XML` the difference looks like so in `/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml`:

`Excel 2007`:

```xml
<dataValidation type="list" allowBlank="1" showInputMessage="1" showErrorMessage="1" sqref="A1">
 <formula1>Sheet2_A1_A5</formula1>
</dataValidation>
```

There "Sheet2_A1_A5" is a named range in the workbook that points to `Sheet2!A1:A5`.

`Excel 365`:

```xml
<x14:dataValidation type="list" allowBlank="1" showInputMessage="1" showErrorMessage="1">
 <x14:formula1>
  <xm:f>Sheet2!A1:A5</xm:f>
 </x14:formula1>
 <xm:sqref>A1</xm:sqref>
</x14:dataValidation>
```

There "Sheet2!A1:A5" is a direct reference to the other worksheet.

As you see, the new `x14:dataValidation` is in a separate name space. This is not covered by `apache poi` until now.

What one could do is using low level `XML` parsing methods to get the new `XSSFX14DataValidation`s additional to the `XSSFDataValidation`s. The following example shows a working draft for how to do this.

```java
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddressList;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

class ReadExcelDataValidaton {

 static java.util.List<XmlObject> getX14DataValidations(XSSFSheet sheet) {
  java.util.List<XmlObject> x14DataValidations = new java.util.ArrayList<XmlObject>();
  XmlCursor cursor = sheet.getCTWorksheet().newCursor();
  cursor.selectPath(
   "declare namespace x14='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/main' .//x14:dataValidation");
  while(cursor.hasNextSelection()) {
   cursor.toNextSelection();
   XmlObject obj = cursor.getObject();
   x14DataValidations.add(obj);
  }
  return x14DataValidations;
 }

 static void addXSSFX14DataValidations(XSSFSheet sheet, java.util.List<DataValidation> dataValidations) {
  java.util.List<XmlObject> x14DataValidations = getX14DataValidations(sheet);
  for (XmlObject x14DataValidation : x14DataValidations) {
   XSSFX14DataValidation xssfX14DataValidation = new XSSFX14DataValidation(x14DataValidation);
   dataValidations.add(xssfX14DataValidation);
  }
 }

 static java.util.List<DataValidation> getDataValidations(Sheet sheet) {
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  java.util.List<DataValidation> dataValidations = (java.util.List<DataValidation>)sheet.getDataValidations();
  if (sheet instanceof XSSFSheet) {
   addXSSFX14DataValidations((XSSFSheet)sheet, dataValidations);
  } 
  return dataValidations;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./Excel.xlsx"));
  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  java.util.List<DataValidation> dataValidations = getDataValidations(sheet);
  for (DataValidation dataValidation : dataValidations) {
   System.out.println(dataValidation);
   System.out.println(dataValidation.getValidationConstraint().getFormula1());
  }
  workbook.close();
 }
}

class XSSFX14DataValidation implements DataValidation {

 private DataValidationConstraint validationConstraint;
 private int errorStyle;
 private boolean emptyCellAllowed;
 private boolean suppressDropDownArrow;
 private boolean showPromptBox;
 private boolean showErrorBox;
 private String promptBoxTitle;
 private String promptBoxText;
 private String errorBoxTitle;
 private String errorBoxText;
 private CellRangeAddressList regions;

 public XSSFX14DataValidation(XmlObject x14DataValidation) {
  String type = "";
  XmlObject typeAttribute = x14DataValidation.selectAttribute(new QName("type"));
  if (typeAttribute != null) type = typeAttribute.newCursor().getTextValue();
  Integer validationType = DataValidationConstraint.ValidationType.ANY;
  if ("CUSTOM".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
   validationType = DataValidationConstraint.ValidationType.FORMULA;
  } else if ("DATE".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
   validationType = DataValidationConstraint.ValidationType.DATE;
  } else if ("DECIMAL".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
   validationType = DataValidationConstraint.ValidationType.DECIMAL;
  } else if ("LIST".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
   validationType = DataValidationConstraint.ValidationType.LIST;
  } else if ("NONE".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
   validationType = DataValidationConstraint.ValidationType.ANY;
  } else if ("TEXT_LENGTH".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
   validationType = DataValidationConstraint.ValidationType.TEXT_LENGTH;
  } else if ("TIME".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
   validationType = DataValidationConstraint.ValidationType.TIME;
  } else if ("WHOLE".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
   validationType = DataValidationConstraint.ValidationType.INTEGER;
  }

  String operator = "";
  XmlObject operatorAttribute = x14DataValidation.selectAttribute(new QName("operator"));
  if (operatorAttribute != null) operator = operatorAttribute.newCursor().getTextValue();
  Integer operatorType = DataValidationConstraint.OperatorType.IGNORED;
  if ("BETWEEN".equalsIgnoreCase(operator)) {
   operatorType = DataValidationConstraint.OperatorType.BETWEEN;
  } else if ("NOT_BETWEEN".equalsIgnoreCase(operator)) {
   operatorType = DataValidationConstraint.OperatorType.NOT_BETWEEN;
  } else if ("EQUAL".equalsIgnoreCase(operator)) {
   operatorType = DataValidationConstraint.OperatorType.EQUAL;
  } else if ("NOT_EQUAL".equalsIgnoreCase(operator)) {
   operatorType = DataValidationConstraint.OperatorType.NOT_EQUAL;
  } else if ("GREATER_THAN".equalsIgnoreCase(operator)) {
   operatorType = DataValidationConstraint.OperatorType.GREATER_THAN;
  } else if ("GREATER_OR_EQUAL".equalsIgnoreCase(operator)) {
   operatorType = DataValidationConstraint.OperatorType.GREATER_OR_EQUAL;
  } else if ("LESS_THAN".equalsIgnoreCase(operator)) {
   operatorType = DataValidationConstraint.OperatorType.LESS_THAN;
  } else if ("LESS_OR_EQUAL".equalsIgnoreCase(operator)) {
   operatorType = DataValidationConstraint.OperatorType.LESS_OR_EQUAL;
  }

  String formula1 = null;
  XmlObject[] xmlObjects = x14DataValidation.selectChildren(
    new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/main", "formula1"));
  if (xmlObjects.length > 0) {
   XmlObject formula1Element = xmlObjects[0];
   formula1 = formula1Element.newCursor().getTextValue();
  }

  String formula2 = null;
  xmlObjects = x14DataValidation.selectChildren(
    new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/main", "formula2"));
  if (xmlObjects.length > 0) {
   XmlObject formula2Element = xmlObjects[0];
   formula2 = formula2Element.newCursor().getTextValue();
  }

  this.validationConstraint = new XSSFDataValidationConstraint(validationType, operatorType, formula1, formula2);

  this.regions = new CellRangeAddressList();
  String sqref = "";
  xmlObjects = x14DataValidation.selectChildren(
    new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/excel/2006/main", "sqref"));
  if (xmlObjects.length > 0) {
   XmlObject sqrefElement = xmlObjects[0];
   sqref = sqrefElement.newCursor().getTextValue();
  }
  String [] refs = sqref.split(" ");
  for (String ref : refs) {
   CellRangeAddress address = CellRangeAddress.valueOf(ref);
   this.regions.addCellRangeAddress(address);
  }

  String allowBlank = "";
  XmlObject allowBlankAttribute = x14DataValidation.selectAttribute(new QName("allowBlank"));
  if (allowBlankAttribute != null) allowBlank = allowBlankAttribute.newCursor().getTextValue();
  this.emptyCellAllowed = ("1".equals(allowBlank) || "TRUE".equalsIgnoreCase(allowBlank));

  String showInputMessage = "";
  XmlObject showInputMessageAttribute = x14DataValidation.selectAttribute(new QName("showInputMessage"));
  if (showInputMessageAttribute != null) showInputMessage = showInputMessageAttribute.newCursor().getTextValue();
  this.showPromptBox = ("1".equals(showInputMessage) || "TRUE".equalsIgnoreCase(showInputMessage));

  String showErrorMessage = "";
  XmlObject showErrorMessageAttribute = x14DataValidation.selectAttribute(new QName("showErrorMessage"));
  if (showErrorMessageAttribute != null) showErrorMessage = showErrorMessageAttribute.newCursor().getTextValue();
  this.showErrorBox = ("1".equals(showErrorMessage) || "TRUE".equalsIgnoreCase(showErrorMessage));

  //TODO: complete

 }

 public DataValidationConstraint getValidationConstraint() {
  return this.validationConstraint;
 }

 public void setErrorStyle(int errorStyle) {
  this.errorStyle = errorStyle;
 }

 public int getErrorStyle() {
  return this.errorStyle;
 }

 public void setEmptyCellAllowed(boolean allowed) {
  this.emptyCellAllowed = allowed;
 }

 public boolean getEmptyCellAllowed() {
  return this.emptyCellAllowed;
 }

 public void setSuppressDropDownArrow(boolean suppress) {
  this.suppressDropDownArrow = suppress;
 }

 public boolean getSuppressDropDownArrow() {
  return this.suppressDropDownArrow;
 }

 public void setShowPromptBox(boolean show) {
  this.showPromptBox = show;
 }

 public boolean getShowPromptBox() {
  return this.showPromptBox;
 }

 public void setShowErrorBox(boolean show) {
  this.showErrorBox = show;
 }

 public boolean getShowErrorBox() {
  return this.showErrorBox;
 }

 public void createPromptBox(String title, String text) {
  this.promptBoxTitle = title;
  this.promptBoxText = text;
 }

 public String getPromptBoxTitle() {
  return this.promptBoxTitle;
 }

 public String getPromptBoxText() {
  return this.promptBoxText;
 }
 
 public void createErrorBox(String title, String text) {
  this.errorBoxTitle = title;
  this.errorBoxText = text;
 }

 public String getErrorBoxTitle() {
  return this.errorBoxTitle;
 }

 public String getErrorBoxText() {
  return this.errorBoxText;
 }

 public CellRangeAddressList getRegions() {
  return this.regions;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Axel. I'm going to have a try.

Comment: Axel, it's cool, your code works well. Thank you so much.