# Reading all dropdown options from .xlsx sheet

Tags: java, selenium, apache-poi

I have a dropdown in an Excel(.xlxs) and I want to get all its options in a list.

I tried using the below code, but I didn't get any data.

```
 public String[] getCellDropdownValues() {
        List<XSSFDataValidation> dataValidations = (List<XSSFDataValidation>) sheet.getDataValidations();
        Iterator<XSSFDataValidation> iterator = dataValidations.iterator();
        XSSFDataValidation dataValidation = iterator.next();
        String[] explicitListValues = dataValidation.getValidationConstraint().getExplicitListValues();
        return explicitListValues;
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62695000/sheet-getdatavalidations-returns-an-empty-list-when-a-cell-is-validated-by-a-s/62727267#62727267.

Comment: @AxelRichter - Sorry, I am new to using Apache POI, having trouble understanding the code you have referred. Is there any other way or a more simple way of just getting all the dropdown options from an xlxs cell in an arraylist?

Comment: No, as far as I know there is no simpler way. There are multiple different kinds of data validation list constraints in current `Excel`. My code is able reading `Formula1` of all of them. It is complete. Simply copy/paste/compile/run. Of course `Excel.xlsx` referred in main method must be stored somewhere.

Comment: @AxelRichter - Okay understood let me try once but I can see the the use of only sheet. I have multiple columns and rows in my sheet and I just want the dropdown data of a particular cell. Could you please guide me on this?

Comment: But this was not what you asked here. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57624680/how-to-get-datavalidation-source-for-a-cell-in-java-using-poi/57635240#57635240 for how to get data validation list from a cell. But this does not support the new `x14` data validation features. So you might need to combine both answers.

Answer (score 1):

**There might be following issue with your code:**

1. You have mentioned .xlxs, Kindly rename it with ".xlsx" (currently ".xlxs").
2. Verify your sheet for a valid dropdown value.

[image]

[image]

3. Incorrect import or you haven't mentioned the code to get the workbook and the sheet.

**Imports:**

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDataValidation;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
```

**Code:**

```
public static String[] getCellDropdownValues() throws Exception {
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/data.xlsx"));
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
    List<XSSFDataValidation> dataValidations = (List<XSSFDataValidation>) sheet.getDataValidations();
    Iterator<XSSFDataValidation> iterator = dataValidations.iterator();
    XSSFDataValidation dataValidation = iterator.next();
    String[] explicitListValues = dataValidation.getValidationConstraint().getExplicitListValues();
    return explicitListValues;
}
```

**Code Output:**
[image]

**Note: Same code is working fine for me.**